# clearing form history with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way I can clear the form history with **jQuery**.

I have a form and I can view the history of my input elements in a dropdown. I woz wondering If I can clear those input fields history with javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("#field_id").attr("autocomplete", "off");
```

Or, on your html element:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A new HTML5 form attribute called `autocomplete` should *help* you with this.

Use it like so:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" autocomplete="off" />
```

Or on the entire form:

```
<form autocomplete="off"></form>
```

Remember, you can only suggest what you want the browser to do... you can't force it.  As browsers begin implementing the HTML5 standard more and more then this will take effect more often.  But you can begin using it now.